$2^x + 3^x + 6^x = x^2$, no. Of solutions. (Without differentiation)
I know this problem can be approached and even be solved by differentiation.
The differentiation is always positive (for $x<0$, i also proved $x$ needs to be negative) so strictly increasing and hence it cuts $x$-axis just once, by hit and trial we also get $x=-1$ as a solution. It will also be the only solution.
However the twist is that my professor asked to solve it without differentiation.
Now my very first thought was log because I see powers i don't want in power, i also tried but am not getting anywhere, please tell, thanks.

To narrow in on the problem, it seems that you want to show that $2^x+3^x+6^x-x^2$ is strictly increasing for $x<0$ without using calculus.

Yes @Semiclassical , also i forgot to mention that we cannot draw graphs. I know we can draw graphs of lhs and rhs seperately and see intersections but that is also not allowed. We strictly need to solve it by equations.

There's a few other "prove monotonic without differentiation" exercises in the MathSE archives but they tend to be a bit too simple for what you're doing.

It may be interesting to consider $2^x+3^x+6^x$ is in between $3\cdot 2^x$ and $3\cdot 6^x$, but if that is too broad you can get more specific along those lines.

For $c > 0,   2^c > 1.$   For real $a < b,  2^b = 2^a 2^{b-a},$  but $b-a > 0$  so $2^b > 2^a$  Same $3^b > 3^a$  and  $6^b > 6^a$

To build from what @Semiclassical said, both $2^x+3^x+6^x$ and $-x^2$ are monotonically increasing for $x\le 0$. Exponentials are inherently increasing, and the quadratic has its vertex at $x=0$. Their sum must therefore also be increasing. Is that not sufficient?

WTP? I'm not getting it. In the interval $(-\infty,0]$ the function $f(x)=2^x+3^x+6^x$ is strictly increasing as a sum of strictly increasing functions. But the function $g(x)=x^2$ is strictly decreasing. This suffices for showing that their graphs can intersect at at most one point.

Out of curiosity, how did you prove (without calculus) that $x$ needs to be negative? (please include this in your post rather than in a comment).

@AnneBauval , I couldn't prove it without calculus, I wrote it in the para where I was telling about differentiation approach, sorry if there sentencing indicated otherwise.

@JyrkiLahtonen , In this question we cannot talk about strictly increasing or decreasing, no calculus. But if you could prove it without calculus (and just plotting/putting in numbers that to prove it is strictly increasing) then it is acceptable.

@EricSnyder , no monotonicity related talks as we can't use anything from calculus chapter... Actually I was approaching every problem with calculus so my professor got a bit angry that I don't explore other methods and gave this assignment a while ago, i am allowed for helps/hints. Now the solution needs to be totally free of calculus.

If $x>y$ then $x-y>0$. By the properties of exponentiation this means that $2^{x-y}>1$. Multiplying that inequality by $2^y$ gives $2^x>2^y$, which is what the doctor ordered. Of course, there may be missing details depending on how $2^x$ was defined in your course. $3^x$ and $6^x$ are done in the same way. $x^2$ is simpler. No derivatives needed. What else do you mean by "no calculus"?

Ok thanks. Got it

Obviously, $\color{blue}{x=-1}$ is a solution to the given equation $2^x+3^x+6^x=x^2$ as $\frac12+\frac13+\frac16=1$. Let's check out whether other real solutions also exist.
First, note that the functions $2^x,3^x,6^x,x$, and $\ln(1+x)$ are clearly increasing in their respective domains.

When $x=-r<-1$, then $a^r<a$ for $a\in(0,1)$ and $r>1$. So,

$$2^x+3^x+4^x=\frac 1{2^r}+\frac{1}{3^r}+\frac{1}{6^r}<\frac12+\frac13+\frac16=1$$
But $x^2=r^2>1$. So, it has no solution for $x<-1$ or $x\in(-\infty,-1)$.

When $-1<x=r-1<1$ or $0<r<2$, $$2^x+3^x+6^x=\frac{2^r}2+\frac{3^r}3+\frac{6^r}6>\frac12+\frac13+\frac16=1$$
But $x^2<1$. So, it has no solution for $-1<x<1$ or $x\in(-1,1)$.

When $x\geq1$,
$$2^x+3^x+6^x>6^x= e^{x\ln6}> e^{2\ln\left( x+1\right)}=\left(x+1\right)^2>x^2$$
This is because $x>\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\ldots,\forall x>0$ and $\ln6=1.79\ldots>2\ln2=1.38\ldots$. Intuitively, the function $\ln(1+x)$ grows slower than the linear function $x$, which is why $x$ remains greater than $\ln(1+x)$. So, no solution exists for $x\geq1$ or $x\in[1,\infty)$.


Hence, $\color{blue}{x=-1}$ is the only real solution to the equation $2^x+3^x+6^x=x^2$. $\blacksquare$

How did you get to result that 2^x, 3^x,etc and ln(1+x) is increasing? (Without calculus and graphing)

@ArhamShah It is intuition. $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdots$ is increasing. $1+x$ is increasing. So is $\ln(1+x)$. It is obvious. You can visualize their graphs also.

@ArhamShah It is a basic concept that when we increase exponents, the powers also increase. When we increase $(1+x)$, we should also increase $\ln(1+x)$ so that $e^{\ln(1+x)}$ also increases.

@ArhamShah Calculus is used to deal with advanced cases. Just like we can find the area of a triangle without calculus. We do not need calculus here. Only intuition is enough.

Ok thanks. Got it

@ArhamShah Nice. You are just overlooking it. That's it. Please do not forget fundamental concepts while studying advanced concepts.
